# Nested comments in PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I searched through the forums but couldn't get an authoritative answer. I want to implement a nested comment structure in a way like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>This is the parent first comment!
        <ul>
            <li>This is the reply for the first parent comment!
                <ul>
                    <li>This is a reply for the first reply of the parent comment!</li>
                    <li>This is a third reply for the first parent comment!</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>This is another reply for first parent comment!</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>This is gonna be parent second comment!
        <ul>
            <li>This is a reply for the second comment!</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>This is fourth parent comment!</li>
</ul>
```

The dump for my table is below:

```
+----+------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| id | text                                                       | parent |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|  1 | This is the parent first comment!                          |      0 |
|  2 | This is gonna be parent second comment!                    |      0 |
|  3 | This is the reply for the first parent comment!            |      1 |
|  4 | This is another reply for first parent comment!            |      1 |
|  5 | This is a reply for the first reply of the parent comment! |      3 |
|  6 | This is a reply for the second comment!                    |      2 |
|  7 | This is a third reply for the first parent comment!        |      3 |
|  8 | This is fourth parent comment!                             |      0 |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
```

I know how to use `mysql_query()` and `while()` loops. A beginner in PHP & MySQL. Please help me out.

Comment: You can see my example https://github.com/shahovkit/nested-comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had done something similar for my blogpost. Yet, I just tried out with the same data. When you say **nested comments** it is better you can use **nested functions** this way:

```
function getComments($parent)
{
    # Get the data from SQL.
    # Check if it has nested comments.
    if (hasComments())
        getComments($child); # $child is the ID of the current comment.
}
```

To make it this way, I have imported your data to MySQL and tried this:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root');
    mysql_select_db('nestedcomments');
    function getComments($parent)
    {
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `nestcomm` WHERE `parent` = $parent");
        if (mysql_num_rows($res))
        {
            echo "<ul>\n";
            while (($dat = mysql_fetch_array($res)) !== false)
                echo "<li>", $dat["text"], getComments($dat["id"]), "</li>\n";
            echo "</ul>\n";
        }
        else
            echo ($parent === 0) ? 'No Comments!' : "";
    }
    getComments(0);
?>
```

As I said before I have used nested functions, and as you asked the output is almost same (without the braces) this way:

```
<ul>
<li>This is the parent first comment!<ul>
<li>This is the reply for the first parent comment!<ul>
<li>This is a reply for the first reply of the parent comment!</li>
<li>This is a third reply for the first parent comment!</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>This is another reply for first parent comment!</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>This is gonna be parent second comment!<ul>
<li>This is a reply for the second comment!</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>This is fourth parent comment!</li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps out.

Comment: Looks like this is what I want. Let me implement and check.

Comment: Note that while this will give the correct result, it fires off one query per comment, so it will be slow. But if you're just doing this as an experiment, or for a site with few users and comments, it might be just fine for you.

Comment: Just copied the whole PHP Function. It works. Can you make it possible to add the spaces too? Is it really possible to count to that level by level?

Comment: @MarkByers I just tried an experiment to find what the OP wants. Yeah, even I know this is not the right model for a nested comment.

Comment: @MarkByers It is just for a simple one, just for my class to comment and leave replies. More to test! :) And yeah, this works perfectly for my use case. Thanks.

Comment: @Aishu What Mark Byers said is right. Even I would say that it is better to change the structure of the database. Check out Wordpress's comment style by downloading it. You might be able to learn new stuff. :)

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @Truth From which version of PHP, this has started?

Comment: @PraveenKumar: PDO is the newer one, and it is **included by default** since 5.1.

Comment: @Truth I asked about the deprecation status of `mysql_*` functions. Good thing I saw yours because, I have done a hundreds of apps, all which depend on `mysql_*` functions extensively. Is there a best way to convert them into PDO? And, can I use `mysqli_*` functions instead of `mysql_*` functions? Are both same? My database is gonna be MySQL.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: It's easier to convert from mysql to mysqli, so for old projects, do so. Learn PDO and use it in newer projects.

Comment: @uzyn This was the meant syntax! And the script outputs this way!

Comment: **Beware**: This solution executes multiple queries against your database. Recursively running queries in a for/while loop is considered as bad practice. This may really hurt your overall system/site performance when your data grows.

Answer (score 16):

There are several different ways to store heirarchical data in MySQL. Check out Bill Karwin's [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data) that demonstrates four options.

- Adjacency List
- Path Enumeration
- Nested Sets
- Closure Table

---

You are using the **adjacency list** model for storing heirarchical data, but unfortunately this is the **hardest** model you could choose for querying subtrees.

[image: nested sets query subtree]

Your options are:

- Change to a different model.
- Restrict queries to n levels deep.
- Use a stored procedure to query recursively. For more information about this, see Quassnoi's series of articles - [Hierarchical queries in MySQL](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/).

Comment: Is the Adjacency list you said related to any graph models?

Comment: Yes. The OPs structure can be regarded as a tree (a graph without cycles).

Comment: Change the model as in? Are you talking about the database table structure?

Comment: @Aishu: Yes. With any of the models apart from the one you have chosen, your task would be easy.